# Is it possible to send POST request from arduino uno via COM3 serial port?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

Can i send POST request to server with Json data from arduino uno without ethernet/wifi module just using com3 serial port?

Comment: there is an old and not maintained library which attempted to do that. https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/SerialIP/

Answer (score 1):

Not with only Arduino Code.
You could code a "host program" in another language (e.g. Python, Java, Processing, etc.) that reads the Arduino's Serial data, and from the "host program" send the request for the Arduino.